# JavaFX close connections before application closes

Tags: java, javafx

I create connections in my controller when I run my program (`mysql`, `ssh`). When I close the program, is there some method that I can Override that will allow me to close those when the application is closed?

There is this when the application is `initialized`:

```
public class MainController implements Initializable{
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
        // Initialization code here...
    }
}
```

Is there anything similar to that for when the application is about to close?

Answer (score 3):

According to this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html

you can override the stop() method:

```
stop(): This method is called when the application should stop, 
and provides a convenient place to prepare for application exit 
and destroy resources.
```

Alternatively you could always attach a shutdown hook to your application the standard way:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
  @Override
    public void run() {
      shutdown();
    }
  });
}

public void shutdown() {
  // finalizing code
}
```

Comment: That works, but when I am connected to SSH with `JSch` it doesn't work for some reason. Any ideas why?